# Magento tutorial

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

Can any one Show me the best way to change the product price on the fly.
I sell bullion based products, which price changes every 2 minutes. So is there a way to achieve this ?

### Info

It around 200 products and i am getting the info from a third party script. Updating the price in cron does not seems the best way, as the price is updating in every 2 min. The script itself could take around 2 min to run in cron.

Answer (score 1):

Your exact strategy on this is likely to require more information.

- How many products do you need to update
- how are you getting the price information
- when do you intend on showing the customer the price
- what if the price changes in the cart and checkout ?

I am working on a project that has a similar requirement - changes to product prices occur frequently.

We are generating those prices in cron running every minute and then setting the product special price to te currently active price. This allows us to use the magento core for handling day to day activity.

You could perhaps look at using an observer on product load to retrieve in real time the current price - your source data would need an API to do this.

You can do similar when adding the product to the cart. When the product is in the cart if you set a price it can use this and override changes in price this would be a decision you need to make.

Comment: Updated the info.